# Downloading files from in android webview application using android download manager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have an android webview based app for my website. I am looking to allow users to download a file from in the application itself without opening an external browser. I have read many posts on how to implement the downloadmanager in the main activity but I just can't seem to properly apply the code. I will attach the code of my mainactivity.java and if someone can help me properly code it in it will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my mainactivity.java

```
package com.android.mypackage;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Welcome to WARAZ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // REMOTE RESOURCE
         mWebView.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation is the same. Just put all code in the event handler for clicking a download link. Or call the function who does that.

Comment: `I am looking to allow users to download a file from in the application itself` What do you mean exactly? The user will click a download link in the web page displayed by the webview i think. Or not?

Comment: @blackapps I want them to click the link on my website and have the file download without opening an external browser

Comment: ok. well add the eventhandler code to begin with.

Comment: @blackapps I am a beginner and I'm having a hard time properly adding the code in by myself. I am basically just asking for help from a more experienced programmer to add in the code.

Comment: See your tag android-webview. Read the pages there. Or pages tagged android. Every few days your download problem is discussed. You will find it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938937/error-with-downloading-a-pdf-file-with-webview-android

Comment: @blackapps I appreciate the help. I've read through many of those posts and can't seem to figure it out. All I want is for someone to implement the code properly and I'll see where I went wrong. I am very new to this....

Comment: Well i gave you a link where you can find all. How about that?